# Cross project Endpoint access - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently I have 2 projects

Project A 
- App engine is deployed with open api Endpoint. 
I have able to access endpoint with the service account created in project A

Open api's

```
    security:
  - google_id_token: []
  - api_key: []

securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
      google_id_token:
        authorizationUrl: ""
        flow: "implicit"
        type: "oauth2"
        x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
        x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
```

Issue is when i am trying to sing in Project B service account to use project A endpoint

Error:

```
 "Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account"
```

And i am not able to find any role related to "singBlob"

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign data with IAM, the service account passed to the API needs to have certain permissions. When obtaining this error you need to go to the IAM and admin page of the GCP console, and [assign](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) the

> [Service account token creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_token_creator_role)

to the service account in question.